# How Should I Represent Time of Day in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, time, format

I would like to store time of day - e.g. 18:00 in an Oracle database, and would like to do comparison queries with it.

What is the recommended way to represent a time of day column?

Comment: This is a design issue which ultimately comes from your requirements. You need to consider whether it is the time of a specific day (ie a date/timestamp) or a 'recurring' time (like you'd get in a train timetable). Then consider if it needs to be timezone aware (including daylight savings), and how. Would comparisons be just before/after tests or does it need to cover maths (eg 20 minutes later, 1 hr earlier etc). How does that work across midnight ?

Comment: Since Oracle does not have a "time-of-day" data type, you will likely have to use the "date" data type (much better than other solutions, such as character string or number). How to do that depends on your data AND type of operations you need to perform. For example, if your "comparison" means equality or "between" comparisons only, such as "time...  between 03:00 and 22:00" then adding all the times to a fixed date, such as 12/31/2000, would work. For more complicated operations, another solution may be more efficient... what is best depends on your requirements as Gary said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a column with datetime typoe and so yo can perform comparisio on datetime column  and show th time  with to_char(datetime)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

eg :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_col, 'HH24:MI')
FROM your_table;
```

for format models see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm